# Hibernate throws NamingException looking up my datasource into liferay context

Tags: hibernate, jpa, liferay, context.xml

I've a liferay (6.1.0 bundled with tomcat 7.0.23) portlet that use a own database different by liferay db.

Well, if I access db by tomcat connection pooling it works

```
        String jndiName = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB";       
    try {

        Context ctxt = new InitialContext();
        Name name = ctxt.getNameParser( "" ).parse( jndiName);
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctxt.lookup( name ); //I've got the DataSource

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("[NamingException]");
    }
```

If I use JPA (implemented by Hibernate 4), it throws NamingException.
This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myPU">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
   <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my (simple) code

```
            EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU");
        EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
```

and this is the relevant part of the stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB]
at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111).
```

Well, I downloaded the hibernate sources and this is the piece of code of the class org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl

```
    public Object locate(String jndiName) {
    final InitialContext initialContext = buildInitialContext();
    final Name name = parseName( jndiName, initialContext );
    try {
        return initialContext.lookup( name );
    }
    catch ( NamingException e ) {
        throw new JndiException( "Unable to lookup JNDI name [" + jndiName + "]", e );
    }
    finally {
        cleanUp( initialContext );
    }
}
```

where buildInitialContext() does new InitialContext()

So, it seems that hibernate and me do the same thing but for some matter the InitialContext is different ad so the lookup by hibernate fails.

Be in mind that my context is defined under TOMCAT_HOME/Catalina/localhost.
Be in mind that if in persistence.xml I don't use the tomcat datasource but put the connection parameters...it works!

```
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myuser" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypwd" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where you have resource definition of java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB ? is it available for your context ?

Comment: As I wrote, the context is defined in  TOMCAT_HOME/Catalina/localhost/context.xml.

Hibernate that does not find it it's the problem

Comment: did you able to solve this?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember. I will check my backups and answer you a.s.a.p.

Comment: @user3703071 thanks for the prompt. Please share the solution if possible